# outlook or simplemapi access email address prompt not working

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook-2016

I have looked extensively and cannot find anyone else having this issue. We have an old Omnis (4.3.1.4) Program using an msmail2.dll (extension to Omnis) using simpleMAPI to read the Outlook (2016) inbox and send mail. (yes we are working to upgrade to the Outlook object model) Sending email works fine but reading the inbox and receiving the usual prompt "a program is trying to access email address info.... allow for 1 to 10 min", does not work.  There is a "ghost" bar across the prompt and there are no time options(1 to 10 min) in the list.
[Outlook Prompt to allow access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gr3bB.png)

Oddly, if you click the Allow button repeatedly, once for each mail in the inbox, the inbox will be read on most systems but not all.  Windows defender scanning each email?? I can find no setting for such

I have spent the day fooling with registry entries trying to disable the prompt but no joy.(not a good idea anyway)  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: I uninstalled Office 2016 and installed clean, turned off Office updates and was able to get the simpleMAPI working again.  Had to use msmapi32.dll version 16.0.11231.20022.  Would like to know more if anyone can contribute.  Uninstall and reinstall is overkill when I am sure there is a dll that simply needs replaced with an older version.

Comment: The use of Simple MAPI is discouraged. It may be altered or unavailable in subsequent versions of Windows.